# Shared quota for few namespaces [kubernetes]

Tags: kubernetes, quota

I'd like to ask if is there possibility to create shared quota for few namespaces, e.g. for team

Scenario:

```
cluster:
100c
100gb ram
```

```
quota for TEAM A 40c/40gb
quota for TEAM B 60c/60gb
```

Some namespaces from TEAM An e.g.

```
teama-dev
teama-test
teama-stage
teama-int
```

Have to be all limited to quota 40c/40gb

Same for TEAM B.

Case is that I don't want specify quotas directly for namespaces, but for team, or group of namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible in Kubernetes today.

OpenShift supports quota across multiple namespaces via [ClusterResourceQuota](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_guide/multiproject_quota.html), and it is possible something like that might make it into Kubernetes in the future, but does not exist yet.